# How can I create loop using int value in c++ (simple)

Tags: c++

I have an integer value, such as 5794.  I want apply a several of calculations on each number without using array

**Example**

```
int encrypt;
cout << "Enter 4 digit numbers to encryption :> ";

cin >> encrypt;

for(int i=1;i<=encrypt;i++){
   cout << encrypt  << endl;
}
```

This code prints the whole number, but I want to print each digit without using array.  If the number is 5794, I want to display:

```
5
7
9
4
```

I do not want it to be displayed like this:

```
5794
```

Comment: Side note: [endl vs '\n'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you have troubles putting other replier's suggestions into code:

```
int divisor = 1000;
std::cout << "enCRAPtion digits:\n";
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
{
    cout << (encrypt / divisor) << "\n\n";
    encrypt = encrypt % divisor;
    divisor = divisor / 10;
}
```

By the way, the word is "encryption" not "encraption".

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code is the closest to the correct, But there is a problem , when print the number as this way, example if the number is (4567), Printed in this way 4 45 456 4567 and I want like this 4 5 6 7 .

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use `modulus` (%) and `division` (/) operator.

If given number has four `digit` then divide it by 1000,100,10,1:

```
std::cout << "\n" << encrypt/1000%10;
std::cout << "\n" << encrypt/100%10;
```

Comment: thanks, but I do not mean this, I want print number like 5487 each number individually not all the numbers together with some. This is the simplest thing I want

Answer (score 1):

well, if you have the number 5794,  you need to mathmatically extract the digits.

HINT: What happens if you divide the number by 1000?

Comment: @Maxpm: thanks, but please give me example code, I'm beginner

Comment: @LionKing `std::cout << encrypt / 1000;`

Comment: @Maxpm: I do not mean this, I want print number like 5487 each number individually Not all the numbers together with some. This is the simplest thing I want

Comment: @LionKing I know.  You need to get single digits out of an arbitrary number.  To do that, use `/` and `%`.

Comment: @Maxpm: thanks for continue help me, Ok but how can I print number like 5974 each single number in line, can you tell me example please .

Comment: @LionKing:  According to your example output, you want one digit per line followed by a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

Scan number, then you can extract each digit using integer division and reminder (%) operators.

Answer (score 0):

is this you want?:

```
// get the number from stdin, std::cin >> v; 
visitNumber(int v)
{
    int v1 = v;
    size_t len = 0;

    while(v1){
        v1 /= 10;    
        ++ len;
    }

    for(int i=len; i>0; --i){
        std::cout << (v/pow(10,i)) << std:endl; // or some other op you favorate
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I do not mean this, I want print number like 5487 each number individually Not all the numbers together with some. This is the simplest thing I want